# What does "in more than two years" mean exactly in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, tense, phrases

In the following sentence

> The ceasefire's one of the agreements that was reached this past week in Sweden where the two sides fighting Yemen's war have been meeting. They've been having their first direct talks **in more than two years**.

What does the "in more than two years" mean exactly? Does it mean "in the **next** two years" or "in the **past** two years", or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That's your first sale in a week."

This means that it's been more than a week since you had a sale.

"That's your first sale in more than a week."

This means it's been more then a week since you last had a sale.

"They've been having their first direct talks in more than two years."

This means that it's been at least two years since their last direct talks and that they're in the middle of direct talks.

Answer (score 1):

That means they hadn’t talked to each other for the last two(or more) years.